# Passing char arrays to a parameterized constructor is failing

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, constructor

I see a problem in passing char array to a function. This is basically a parameterized constructor where I am seeing a problem. The issue is with passing char array to the parameterized constructor.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

 using namespace std;

class kinda
{
int a;
char name[10];

    public: 
    kinda()
    {
        cout<<"in default constr"<<endl;
        a=0;
        name[0]='\0';  
    }

    ~kinda()
    {
        cout<<"in default destr"<<endl;
    }

    kinda(int val,char* naam)
    {
        cout<<"in param constr"<<endl;
        a=val;
        strcpy(name,naam);
    }

    kinda(kinda &obj)
    {
        cout<<"in copy constr"<<endl;
        a=obj.a;
        strcpy(name,obj.name);
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<"obj details"<<endl;
        cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"name="<<name<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    kinda ob,ob1;
    char a[]="prashu";

    ob.display();
    ob(7,a);
    ob.display();

    ob1.display();
    ob1=ob;
    ob1.display();

    return 0;
}
```

and the error I am getting is this:

> [Error] no match for call to '(kinda) (int, char [7])'

Can someone tell me why is this?

Comment: `kinda(int val,char* naam)` is constructor. `ob(7,a);` --> `kinda ob(7,a);`

Comment: C != C++, and this is obviously C++. The C tag should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a constructor on an object that has been constructed already.
Either make the constructor a normal member function or construct the object with the desired constructor right away.

Answer (score 2):

`kinda(int val,char* naam)` can only use to Initialize an object. 
`ob` has Initialized in `kinda ob,ob1;` so it can not be constructed twice.
`ob(7,a);`//error

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a constructor you have to use it where you declare the object.

```
kinda ob(7,a);  // oh make a kinda call it ob and use the constructor
```

Doing it the way you have it is treating it as a function call.

```
kinda ob;
//...
ob(7,a)  // call a function called ob with parameters (7, a)
         // error.  there is no ob function
```

Comment: It's not calling a function called `ob`. It's calling the `operator()` overload of the `kinda` class. Which doesn't exists, so we get no such function.